# Turning rows into columns over a many-to-many table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, left-join

So I have three tables:

Students:

```
StuID
------
1
2
```

StuCon:

```
StuConId   StuID   ConID  StuConType  Priority
----------------------------------------------
1          1       1      Parent      1
2          1       2      Guardian    2
3          2       3      Parent      1
```

Contacts:

```
ConID  ConName ConPhn
----------------------
1      John    5555555
2      Sally   4444444
3      Dana    3333333
```

I'm trying to get results that look like this:

```
StuID  ConID1 StuConType1  ConName1  ConPhone1   ConID2 StuConType2  ConName2  ConPhone2
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      1      Parent        John     5555555     2      Guardian     Sally     4444444
2      3      Parent        Dana     3333333     Null   Null         Null      Null
```

So far the only way I can figure to do that is by making a LOT of left joins (some students have up to 10 contacts so that's 10 left joins for stucon and 10 more for contacts)

I'm quite sure there is a pivot that can be applied here, I just can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: google Dynamic Pivot ..........

Comment: I don't think you need a PIVOT here. Just a join on the first contact set where priority is 1, and a left join on the second contact set where priority is 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do this dynamically:

```
DECLARE @selects VARCHAR(MAX) = '', @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
SELECT @selects += '
     , MAX(CASE WHEN SC.[Priority] = ' + CAST([Priority] AS VARCHAR(255)) + ' THEN C.ConID END) [ConID' + CAST([Priority] AS VARCHAR(255)) + ']
     , MAX(CASE WHEN SC.[Priority] = ' + CAST([Priority] AS VARCHAR(255)) + ' THEN SC.StuConType END) [StuConType' + CAST([Priority] AS VARCHAR(255)) + ']
     , MAX(CASE WHEN SC.[Priority] = ' + CAST([Priority] AS VARCHAR(255)) + ' THEN C.ConName END) [ConName' + CAST([Priority] AS VARCHAR(255)) + ']
     , MAX(CASE WHEN SC.[Priority] = ' + CAST([Priority] AS VARCHAR(255)) + ' THEN C.ConPhn END) [ConPhone' + CAST([Priority] AS VARCHAR(255)) + ']'
FROM StuCon
GROUP BY [Priority]
ORDER BY [Priority];

SET @SQL = 'SELECT StuID' + @selects + ' FROM StuCon SC LEFT JOIN Contacts C ON C.ConID = SC.ConID GROUP BY StuID;';
EXEC(@SQL);
```

Notes: It probably should be a normal `JOIN` on contacts rather than an `LEFT JOIN`, but it's a left join here just in case there's some inconsistency between tables. The `Students` table hasn't been joined to because it's not necessary.

Comment: You don't need dynamic sql here.

Comment: @shawnt00 You don't _need_ it, but given that any student can have up to ten contacts (and assuming this isn't the limit), this is easier than writing several lines out for ten contacts (and assuming that is the maximum)...

Comment: I overlooked the mention of 10 contacts. While there's a certain economy in this method, dynamic sql has a lot of downsides as does the number of columns in the results suddenly changing.

Comment: @shawnt00 The number of columns in the results will change depending on the maximum number of contacts. If 10 is the absolute limit and you don't want to use dynamic SQL for one reason or another, then yes, you can do this without dynamic SQL. If the maximum number changes, then there's going to be missing data though. But yes, there can be issues with dynamic SQL, depending on how you're outputting the data. OP can always `PRINT @SQL` here, if they need to use a static method for some reason.